# Simpledateformat parse issue

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm parsing a date which is in format `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`. One of the sample values is `Thu, 02 Sep 2010 04:03:10 -0700`.

This is the parsing code:

```
SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = FORMATTER.parse(dateString);
```

This works absolutely fine if Phone Language is English but it throws parserException when language is changed to "France" or "Italian". I have even tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault());
```

or for French locale more explicit:

```
SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.French);
```

But no luck.....Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "Thu" is English, you'll want to use `Locale.ENGLISH` to parse it.